# Caching Data .Net 4.0 (Asp.NET)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, caching, objectcache

Can anybody explane me what is  "`CacheSpecificEviction`" in detail and how to avoid it?

I am geting this in `CacheEntryRemovedArguments.RemovedReason`.

Answer (score 2):

CacheSpecificEviction as reason for removing cache entry means "the item was removed, because the cache provider's eviction policy determined it should be removed" - I know, it is pretty unspecific, but it hardly can be more specific, because of many possible cache-engine implementations and their different eviction policies (often configurable, for example in AppFabric Cache aka Velocity). In generel, eviction means "ok, there are risk of running out of memory, we should remove some items - for example these Least Recently Used (LRE eviction policy), or maybe Least Frequently Used with Dynamic Aging (LFDA), etc.". So to get rid of eviction problems, you sould check your cache memory usage and limits, eviction configuration options...