# System.Runtime.Cache expires instantly

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I have a webpage which caches some querystring values for 30 seconds so that it does not receive duplicate values. I am using the following class:

```
public class MyCache   {

private static ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;

public MyCache() { }


public void Insert(string key, string value)
{

    CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
    policy.Priority = CacheItemPriority.Default;
    policy.SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
    policy.RemovedCallback = new CacheEntryRemovedCallback(this.Cacheremovedcallback);

    cache.Set(key, value, policy);
}

public bool Exists(string key)
{
    return cache.Contains(key);
}

public void Remove(string key)
{
    cache.Remove(key);
}

private void Cacheremovedcallback(CacheEntryRemovedArguments arguments)
{      
    FileLog.LogToFile("Cache item removed. Reason: " + arguments.RemovedReason.ToString() +  "; Item: [" +  arguments.CacheItem.Key + ", " + arguments.CacheItem.Value.ToString() + "]");         
}
 }
```

This has worked fine for a couple of weeks then suddenly the cache doesn't keep the values anymore. The CacheRemoved callback fires instantly after an item is inserted into cache and i get the removed reason: **CacheSpecificEviction**
This is running on a Windows Server 2008 SP1, IIS7.5 with .NET 4.0. No changes were applied to the OS or IIS during this time.

Is there a way to solve this and if not, is there a better cache solution to use in a web page ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it possible your cache has reached it's limit in size? Is it removing old items as new ones are added due to space constraints?

Comment: See this post for explanation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380875/caching-data-net-4-0-asp-net

Comment: Will it be possible for you to post a sample solution with the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code of `MemoryCacheStore` (that should be the default store used by `MemoryCache.Default`) it seems that the remove callback with argument `CacheSpecificEviction` is only called when the cache is disposed:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Caching/System/Caching/MemoryCacheStore.cs,230

Look around and make sure your cache object is not being disposed accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

I also found out that the `RemovedCallback` executes if you call `MemoryCache.Set` on an existing item - because `.Set` overwrites the item in cache.

The workaround is to use `.Add` instead of `.Set`

Even though the OP mentions `CacheSpecificEviction` and this that does not answer his question, but just in case someone is facing a similar problem and landed on this question after searching the Web.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30);
```

Thats how I use Cache:

```
public static class CacheHelper
{
    private static ObjectCache _cache;
    private const Double ChacheExpirationInMinutes = 10;

    /// <summary>
    /// Insert value into the cache using
    /// appropriate name/value pairs
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of cached item</typeparam>
    /// <param name="entity">item cached</param>
    /// <param name="key">Name of item</param>
    public static void Add<T>(T entity, string key) where T : class
    {
        if (_cache == null)
        {
            _cache = MemoryCache.Default;
        }
        if (_cache.Contains(key))
            _cache.Remove(key);
        CacheItemPolicy cacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();
        cacheItemPolicy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(ChacheExpirationInMinutes);
        _cache.Set(key, entity, cacheItemPolicy);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove item from cache
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">Name of cached item</param>
    public static void Clear(string key)
    {
        if (_cache == null)
        {
            _cache = MemoryCache.Default;
            return;
        }
        _cache.Remove(key);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve cached item
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of cached item</typeparam>
    /// <param name="key">Name of cached item</param>
    /// <returns>Cached item as type</returns>
    public static T Get<T>(string key) where T : class
    {
        if (_cache == null)
        {
            _cache = MemoryCache.Default;
        }
        try
        {
            return (T)_cache.Get(key);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure how this solves the issue. As they said, it works for a while then stops working.

Comment: Actually you are right. Dont think that it will solve the isue. But this class works for me very well even for massive project with a lot of users.

Comment: I have one idea. Maybe you try to save to your cache object with large relation chain. Something Like User--> NxCategories-->N*MxProducts-->N*M*FxParametrs. What are you holding in your cache?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The class provided has the same behaviour as mine. I believe the problem is somewhere in IIS. As i said, i am using it in a web page. An ID received by the webpage via querystring is cached as string. I just query the cache in Page_Load method and if the value is not there, i insert it.